# How to fix mis-cast floats in IbPy messages

Tags: python, ibpy

I'm using [IbPy](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy) to read current orders.  The response messages which come back to be processed with [EWrapper methods](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/java/java_ewrapper_methods.htm) have some attributes which appear to be of the wrong type.

To start, here is my handler for Order-related messages.  It is intended to catch all messages due to having called `reqAllOpenOrders()`.

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.ext.OrderState import OrderState

_order_resp = dict(openOrderEnd=False, openOrder=[], openStatus=[])

def order_handler(msg):
    """ Update our global Order data response dict
    """
    global _order_resp
    if msg.typeName in ['openStatus', 'openOrder']:
        d = dict()
        for i in msg.items():
            if isinstance(i[1], (Contract, Order, OrderState)):
                d[i[0]] = i[1].__dict__
            else:
                d[i[0]] = i[1]
        _order_resp[msg.typeName].append(d.copy())
    elif msg.typeName == 'openOrderEnd':
        _order_resp['openOrderEnd'] = True
    log.info('ORDER: {})'.format(msg))
```

In the above code, I'm loading all the objects and their attributes to a dict which is then appended to lists within `_order_resp`.

The log output lines show healthy interaction with IB:

```
25-Jan-16 14:57:04 INFO      ORDER: <openOrder orderId=1, contract=<ib.ext.Contract.Contract object at 0x102a98150>, order=<ib.ext.Order.Order object at 0x102a98210>, orderState=<ib.ext.OrderState.OrderState object at 0x102a98350>>)
25-Jan-16 14:57:04 INFO      ORDER: <orderStatus orderId=1, status=PreSubmitted, filled=0, remaining=100, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1114012437, parentId=0, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=0, whyHeld=None>)
25-Jan-16 14:57:04 INFO      ORDER: <openOrderEnd>)
```

But when looking at the data put into the `_order_resp` dict, it looks like some numbers are off:

```
    {
        "contract": {
            "m_comboLegsDescrip": null,
            "m_conId": 265598,
            "m_currency": "USD",
            "m_exchange": "SMART",
...
        },
        "order": {
            "m_account": "DU12345",
            "m_action": "SELL",
            "m_activeStartTime": "",
            "m_activeStopTime": "",
            "m_algoStrategy": null,
            "m_allOrNone": false,
            "m_auctionStrategy": 0,
            "m_auxPrice": 0.0,
            "m_basisPoints": 9223372036854775807,
            "m_basisPointsType": 9223372036854775807,
...
        },
        "orderId": 1,
        "orderState": {
            "m_commission": 9223372036854775807,
            "m_commissionCurrency": null,
            "m_equityWithLoan": "1.7976931348623157E308",
            "m_initMargin": "1.7976931348623157E308",
            "m_maintMargin": "1.7976931348623157E308",
            "m_maxCommission": 9223372036854775807,
            "m_minCommission": 9223372036854775807,
...
        }
    }
],
"openOrderEnd": true,
```

In the source code, we see that [`m_maxCommission`](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/blob/dcee95173a5d2934589dfb09d77d3c808861053e/ib/ext/OrderState.py#L23) is a `float()`, yet the value looks like an int, and is much larger than most commissions people like paying.

Some other keys like `m_equityWithLoan` have string type values, but the source code says that's correct.

How do I fix the case where I'm getting large ints instead of floats?  Is it possible to read the value from memory and reinterpret it as a float?  Is this an Interactive Brokers API problem?