# Python : how to convert max int64 number to float?

Tags: python, floating-point, int64

Is there a way to convert max int64 number to float number?

I have a max int64 number `9223372036854775807` I want to convert this to float or double. How can I do it in python?

I am developing an automated trading system using a well known broker's API. API sent that number as a response to one of my requests.

Comment: `float(9223372036854775807)`

Comment: An integer that size will not be stored precisely in either a float or a double. Would that be a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e, in general floating point is not the best match for values representing money, or similar (assuming that's what the value is about).

Comment: Thanks ilja Everila.

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004621/how-to-fix-mis-cast-floats-in-ibpy-messages, which is about IbPy.

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
a = float(9223372036854775807)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12607306)

Comment: @IgorIvancha: This is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print float(sys.maxint)
```